# Removing attributes of columns in data.frames on multilevel lists in R

Tags: r, list

How do I remove the attributes of the following columns of data.frames on a nested list in R on the fly?

```
List of 1
 $ 0021400001:List of 19
   $ GameSummary      :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  13 variables:
    $ GAME_DATE_EST                   : Factor w/ 1 level "2014-11-09T00:00:00": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
    $ GAME_SEQUENCE                   : Factor w/ 1 level "2": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "2"
    $ GAME_ID                         : Factor w/ 1 level "0021400091": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
    $ GAME_STATUS_ID                  : Factor w/ 1 level "3": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "4" 
   $ SeasonSeries     :'data.frame':    1 obs. of  7 variables:
     $ GAME_ID         : Factor w/ 1 level "0021400001": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "1"
     $ HOME_TEAM_ID    : Factor w/ 1 level "1610612740": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "2"
     $ VISITOR_TEAM_ID : Factor w/ 1 level "1610612753": 1
      - attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
```

Comment: Where did this structure came from? Source is JSON? With what package? `names` attribute is somehow reserved for value names

Comment: made my own script to make a json file from nba.com readable and structured.

Comment: can you `dput` at least a small sample of this object?

Comment: The easiest way I found to get rid of a lot of attributes for a lot of variables was to convert my `data.frame` to a `matrix`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is perhaps too late to answer on this thread, but I wanted to share.

Two solutions :
1. function stripAttributes from merTools package.

2. to remove the attribute ATT from variable VAR in your data-frame MyData:

   ```
   attr(MyData$VAR, "ATT") <- NULL
   ```

If you want to remove several attributes of all variables :

```
For (var in colnames(MyData)) {
     attr(MyData[,deparse(as.name(var))], "ATT_1") <- NULL
     attr(MyData[,deparse(as.name(var))], "ATT_2") <- NULL
}
```

I hope This Helps,
Regards

Answer (score 6):

You could write a function that works on one entry in the list, e.g.

```
one_entry <- function(x) {
    for (i in length(x)) attr(x[[i]], "names") <- NULL
    return(x)
}
```

and then run `lapply`:

```
lapply(my_list, FUN=one_entry)
```

where `mylist` is the data structure in the question.

Answer (score 3):

It's a hack but worked in my case.

```
lapply(my_list, FUN=function(x){data.frame(as.matrix(x),stringsAsFactors = F)})
```

Answer (score 3):

Minor modification to Parisa's code worked for me:

```
for (var in colnames(MyData)) {
  attr(MyData[[deparse(as.name(var))]], "ATT_1") <- NULL
  attr(MyData[[deparse(as.name(var))]], "ATT_2") <- NULL
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you can use `unname` when you want to remove `names` only combined with `lapply`:

```r
dat[] <- lapply(dat, unname)
```

`[]` is used to ensure that the result is still a `data.frame`. You can use `c` to remove almost all other attributes:

```r
dat[] <- lapply(dat, c)
```

For instance, consider:

```r
# setup data.frame to use
dat <- list(X1 = setNames(factor(1:3), letters[1:3]), 
            X2 = setNames(factor(4:6), LETTERS[1:3]))
attr(dat$X1, "xyz") <- "abc"
attr(dat$X2, "abc") <- "xyz"
dat <- as.data.frame(dat)

# remove attributes that are not names
dat[] <- lapply(dat, c) # use [] to preserve data.frame
str(dat) # no attributes. No names either but those are never added in R 3.6.3

# try with list instead
dat <- list(X1 = setNames(factor(1:3), letters[1:3]), 
            X2 = setNames(factor(4:6), LETTERS[1:3]))
attr(dat$X1, "xyz") <- "abc"
attr(dat$X2, "abc") <- "xyz"

# remove names
dat <- lapply(dat, unname) # no need for []
str(dat) # still has other attributes but not names
```

### Details

From `help("c")`:

> ... all attributes except names are removed.

Exceptions applies to factors and integers. See the manual page.

Answer (score 1):

Building up on everything that has already been said, the code below would keep some attributes and remove others for all your variables in data `df`. Just replace the attributes you want to keep in vector `to_keep`. In this case, I am assuming I want to keep attributes "label" and "at1"--assuming they exist, of course.

```r
to_keep <- c("label", "at1")

to_keep_regx <- paste(to_keep, collapse = "|")
  
nn  <- names(df)
for (x in seq_along(nn)) {
  
  ats       <- attributes(df[[x]])
  atsn      <- names(ats)
  to_remove <- atsn[!grepl(to_keep_regx, atsn)]
  
  for (i in seq_along(to_remove)) {
    attr(df[[x]], to_remove[i]) <- NULL
  }

}
```

Best,

Answer (score 0):

Karsten W.'s answer worked for me as I had to remove more than 2 attributes.  Slightly modified to

```
my_list <- lapply(my_list, FUN=one_entry)
```

Answer (score 0):

##### Use the `rm.attr` function in the `utilities` package

You can remove attributes from an object using the `rm.attr` function in the [`utilities` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/utilities/utilities.pdf).  This function removes all non-protected attributes of the input object; it allows you to specify protected attributes that you do not wish to remove.  For input objects that are nested lists, the function also allows you to specify the number of levels in the listing that you wish to apply the removal to.

Since you have no given a reproducible example of your data in the question, I'll show you an example adapted from the documentation for the function.  First we generate an object that is a nested list with attributes and we show its structure.

```
#Create an object with attributes
a <- structure(list(structure(1, x=2, names=3),
               list(0, structure(3, x=4, names=5))),
               x=3, names = 4)

#Show the structure of the object
str(a)
List of 2
 $ 4 : Named num 1
  ..- attr(*, "x")= num 2
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
 $ NA:List of 2
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : Named num 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "x")= num 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "5"
 - attr(*, "x")= num 3
```

Now we can look at the same object with a specified number of levels of its attributes removed.  (Note that, by default, the attribute `names` is a protected attribute, but you can change this if you want.)

```
#Show the structure with one level of attributes removed
str(rm.attr(a, list.levels = 1))
List of 2
 $ 4 : Named num 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
 $ NA:List of 2
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : Named num 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "x")= num 4
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "5"

#Show the structure with two levels of attributes removed
str(rm.attr(a, list.levels = 2))
List of 2
 $ 4 : Named num 1
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "3"
 $ NA:List of 2
  ..$ : num 0
  ..$ : Named num 3
  .. ..- attr(*, "names")= chr "5"
```