# How to erase all attributes?

Tags: r, attr

I want to erase all attributes from data and applied [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28901769/6574038). However neither `one_entry()` (the original)  nor my `one_entry2()` will work and I don't see why.

```
one_entry2 <- function(x) {
  attr(x, "label") <- NULL
  attr(x, "labels") <- NULL
}

> lapply(df1, one_entry2)
$`id`
NULL

$V1
NULL

$V2
NULL

$V3
NULL
```

How can we do this?

*Data:*

```
df1 <- setNames(data.frame(matrix(1:12, 3, 4)), 
                c("id", paste0("V", 1:3)))
attr(df1$V1, "labels") <- LETTERS[1:4]
attr(df1$V1, "label") <- letters[1:4]
attr(df1$V2, "labels") <- LETTERS[1:4]
attr(df1$V2, "label") <- letters[1:4]
attr(df1$V3, "labels") <- LETTERS[1:4]
attr(df1$V3, "label") <- letters[1:4]

> str(df1)
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ id: int  1 2 3
 $ V1: int  4 5 6
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ V2: int  7 8 9
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
 $ V3: int  10 11 12
  ..- attr(*, "labels")= chr  "A" "B" "C" "D"
  ..- attr(*, "label")= chr  "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

Comment: if anyone needs to remove all attributes from one numeric variable, this worked for me: `as.numeric(a)`

Comment: `as.numeric` also removes the names. If you want to keep the names, in particular a named list, something like this could work `as.list(unlist(a))`.

Comment: Or to remove other attributes but keep names for a vector, you can simply use `c(a)`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To remove *all* attributes, how about this

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) { attributes(x) <- NULL; x })
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ id: int  1 2 3
# $ V1: int  4 5 6
# $ V2: int  7 8 9
# $ V3: int  10 11 12
```

Comment: Dear Maurits may I ask what actually `df1[]` does here? I have never encountered this structure before. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @AnoushiravanR. Rather than me doing a poor job rephrasing what other's have said better, have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21165588/what-does-df-do-in-r).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply and the link. No you absolutely did a great job here :) Best wishes.

Answer (score 8):

Simplifying a bit @maurits-evers answer:

```r
df1[] <- lapply(df1, as.vector)
str(df1)
#'data.frame':  3 obs. of  4 variables:
# $ id: int  1 2 3
# $ V1: int  4 5 6
# $ V2: int  7 8 9
# $ V3: int  10 11 12
```

The original answer is by Prof. Brian Ripley in [this R-Help post](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2009-February/382130.html).

In `tidyverse` world:

```r
df1 <- df1 %>% mutate(across(everything(), as.vector))
```

With `data.table`

```r
library(data.table)
# Assuming
# setDT(df1) # or
# df1 <- as.data.table(df1)

df1 <- df1[, lapply(.SD, as.vector)]
```

Answer (score 3):

Provided all the columns are the same type (as in your example) you can do

```
df1[] = c(df1, recursive=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `PKPDmisc` package has a dplyr friendly way to do this:

```
library(PKPDmisc)
df %>% strip_attributes(c("label", "labels"))
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a simple solution (and will not convert a date class to a numeric):

```
df1 <- data.frame(df1)
```

Comment: I do not know why but this was actually the only solution that was working for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For certain situations, a modified version of the answer by @maurits-evers may be useful.

Create a function to remove attributes.

```
remove_attributes <- function(x) {attributes(x) <- NULL; return(x)}
```

To remove attributes from one element in a list.

```
df1$V1 <- remove_attributes(df1$V1)
```

To remove attributes from all elements in a list.

```
df1 <- lapply(df1, remove_attributes)
```