# How to remove attribute metadata from variable in R?

Tags: r, variables, join, dplyr, tidyverse

So I have two dataframes which need to have identical factor levels for a merge. The dataframe `volume_time_tidy` has these attributes on the variable which are messing up my join later on. How do I preserve the contents of the volume to make it just a factor with x levels, no attributes, identical to `probe2`?

```
> str(probe2$weekday)
 Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
> str(volume_time_tidy$weekday)
 Factor w/ 7 levels "Friday","Monday",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6720] "V2" "V2" "V2" "V2" ...
> str(volume_time_tidy$time)
 Factor w/ 96 levels "00:00:00","00:15:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:6720] "V2" "V2" "V2" "V2" ...
> str(probe2$time)
 Factor w/ 96 levels "00:00:00","00:15:00",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

**Data**

```
hm <- merge(0:23, seq(0, 45, by = 15))
chron(time = paste(hm$x, ':', hm$y, ':', 0))

volume_time_tidy <- data.frame('time' = chron(time = paste(hm$x, ':', hm$y, ':', 0)))
volume_time_tidy <- data.frame('time' = volume_time_tidy[order(volume_time_tidy$time), ])

volume_time_tidy <- volume_time_tidy %>%
  t() %>%
  t()

probe2 <- structure(list(tmc_code = structure(c(6L, 6L), .Label = c("110-04623", 
"110-04624", "110-04625", "110-04626", "110-04627", "110N04623", 
"110N04624", "110N04625", "110N04626", "110N04627"), class = "factor"), 
    measurement_tstamp = structure(c(1519862400, 1519862460), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), speed = c(58, 58), average_speed = c(58, 
    58), reference_speed = c(58, 58), confidence_score = c(30, 
    30), cvalue = c(92, 93), weekday = structure(c(5L, 5L), .Label = c("Friday", 
    "Monday", "Saturday", "Sunday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday"
    ), class = "factor"), time = structure(c(1L, 1L), .Label = c("00:00:00", 
    "00:15:00", "00:30:00", "00:45:00", "01:00:00", "01:15:00", 
    "01:30:00", "01:45:00", "02:00:00", "02:15:00", "02:30:00", 
    "02:45:00", "03:00:00", "03:15:00", "03:30:00", "03:45:00", 
    "04:00:00", "04:15:00", "04:30:00", "04:45:00", "05:00:00", 
    "05:15:00", "05:30:00", "05:45:00", "06:00:00", "06:15:00", 
    "06:30:00", "06:45:00", "07:00:00", "07:15:00", "07:30:00", 
    "07:45:00", "08:00:00", "08:15:00", "08:30:00", "08:45:00", 
    "09:00:00", "09:15:00", "09:30:00", "09:45:00", "10:00:00", 
    "10:15:00", "10:30:00", "10:45:00", "11:00:00", "11:15:00", 
    "11:30:00", "11:45:00", "12:00:00", "12:15:00", "12:30:00", 
    "12:45:00", "13:00:00", "13:15:00", "13:30:00", "13:45:00", 
    "14:00:00", "14:15:00", "14:30:00", "14:45:00", "15:00:00", 
    "15:15:00", "15:30:00", "15:45:00", "16:00:00", "16:15:00", 
    "16:30:00", "16:45:00", "17:00:00", "17:15:00", "17:30:00", 
    "17:45:00", "18:00:00", "18:15:00", "18:30:00", "18:45:00", 
    "19:00:00", "19:15:00", "19:30:00", "19:45:00", "20:00:00", 
    "20:15:00", "20:30:00", "20:45:00", "21:00:00", "21:15:00", 
    "21:30:00", "21:45:00", "22:00:00", "22:15:00", "22:30:00", 
    "22:45:00", "23:00:00", "23:15:00", "23:30:00", "23:45:00"
    ), class = "factor")), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Does this earlier question help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28873323/removing-attributes-of-columns-in-data-frames-on-multilevel-lists-in-r

Comment: I did in fact see that however it did not work @ChuckP

Comment: Your sample data doesn't really match your scenario but when I apply `attr(volume_time_tidy$time, "format") <- NULL` the attribute "format" goes away.  Care to dput(head(probe2))?

Comment: Added; so something I realized is that the issue is "fixed" after creation of the data, but eventually i transpose it twice and them the metadata wont go away